# C# String/StringBuilder MemoryException on Large set of Replaces

Tags: c#, string, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I am trying to figure out a better way to manipulate a large string and using both string and string builder I am unable to.
What I have below is a function that takes in a string and we search that string with regex to find any links. Any occurances of links I want to wrap them in a valid link text. My issue is , I have a database entry (string) with 101 link values present that need to be replaced and I am getting memory issues.

Is there a better way around this solution. I have included it with both string.replace and stringbuilder.replace and neither work

```
    var resultString = new StringBuilder(testb);
    Regex regx = new Regex(@"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection mactches = regx.Matches(txt);

    foreach (Match match in mactches)
    {
        if(match.Value.StartsWith("http://") || match.Value.StartsWith("https://"))
            fixedurl = match.Value;
        else
            fixedurl = "http://" + match.Value;

         resultString.Replace(match.Value, "<a target='_blank' class='ts-link ui-state-default' href='" + fixedurl + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
        //testb = testb.Replace(match.Value, "<a target='_blank' class='ts-link ui-state-default' href='" + fixedurl + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere string builder, also don't parse HTML with regex use HTML parser, probably in this way you will not have any problem at all. If you post **small** html and explain what you want to do I can show you how to do it with html agility pack.

Comment: Can't you simply use `Regex.Replace()`?

Comment: I'd use `HtmlAgilityPack` instead.

Comment: @mybirthname it looks like the function isn't *parsing* HTML - it searches an arbitrary text for something that looks like a link. The regex looks as scary as [the infamous e-mail regex](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), though.

Comment: `resultString` is populated from `testb`, but the regex matching against `txt`.  There might be some issue there.

Comment: resultString and testb are both there as I was just showing 2 test cases  that I was using. One was string.replace and the other was with stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.  It may perform better in your specific case.

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[.\!\/\\w]*))?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

string resultString = regx.Replace(txt, (match) => 
{
    string fixedurl = (match.Value.StartsWith("http://") || match.Value.StartsWith("https://"))
        ? match.Value
        : "http://" + match.Value;

     return "<a target='_blank' class='ts-link ui-state-default' href='" + fixedurl + "'>" + match.Value + "</a>";
});
```

**EDITED:**

BTW, the issue with your code seems to be the `resultString.Replace` call, since it replaces all the occurrences of the string it's probably causing the code to enter into an infinite loop of replacing the same strings over and over again until it hits an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: wdosangos, Thank you this worked. I have looked over your code and now I see what you are doing vs what I was doing and how it could get into a loop, verse your code which uses regex replace to find and just replace the occurances with the return value